# triggering the same function, from 2 different click events, with and without parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function `myFunc` that can be triggered 2 different ways: by clicking div1 or div2.

- If the click came from div2, I'd like to pass some parameters to the function at the time of the call.
- Also, in both cases, I need a reference to the item that was clicked: `$(this)`.

I've tried this code, but the second version (where I'm passing the parameters) gets triggered automatically even without me clicking anything. What am I doing wrong, and do I need to pass `this` as a parameter in both cases?

```
$('#div1').live('click', myFunc);
$('#div2').live('click', myFunc('param1 value', 'param2 value'));

function myFunc(param1, param2){
  console.log('inside myFunc');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second line is immediately executing `myFunc`.  Instead, wrap it in an anonymous function:

```
$('#div2').live('click', function() {
    myFunc.apply(this, ['param1 value', 'param2 value']);
});
```

You'll need to use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) or [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to preserve the original context (otherwise `this` in `myFunc` will be the global window object instead of the clicked element).

Answer (score 4):

Replace your second `live` call with:

```
$('#div2').live('click', function() {
    myFunc.call(this, 'param1 value', 'param2 value');
});
```

Or using the new `on` method in jQuery 1.7+ which is proposed as new standard for binding handlers:

```
$(document).on('click', '#div2', function() {
    myFunc.call(this, 'param1 value', 'param2 value');
});
```

Comment: on while you are on replacing, please replace `live()` with `on()`

Comment: @Topener Good call! I still have to get used to the new bind methods in jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is better for you to pass an anonymous function as the handler of the second, and inside it you call "myFunc" as you want.

Example:

```
$('#div1').live('click', myFunc);
$('#div2').live('click', function() {
  myFunc.call(this, 'param1 value', 'param2 value');
});
```

Comment: Fails to preserve `this` for the inner function.

Comment: Yes. I edited following your suggestion, and up-voted your comment also!

Answer (score 1):

Dont use [live](http://api.jquery.com/on/), its deprecated now. Use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

jQuery provides an easy way to pass `data` when an event occurs.
This should be the standard way,

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("body").on("click","#div1", {param1: "param1",param2: "param2"},myFunc);
    $("body").on("click","#div2",myFunc);
    function myFunc(event){
        console.log(this.id);
        if(this.id == 'div1'){
            console.log(event.data.param1);
            console.log(event.data.param2);
        }
    }

});
```

**Edit:**

I dont know what is your context or requirement, but I would have coded like this,

```
$("body").on("click","#div1,#div2",function(){
    if(this.id == 'div1'){
         // the code for div1, use your params here.   
    }
    else{
        // the code for div2
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this on this way.
You must define a function inline, and call myFunc from it.

```
$('#div1').live('click', myFunc);
$('#div2').live('click', function(){ return myFunc('param1 value', 'param2 value'); } );
```

Comment: This answer fails to preserve `this` for the inner function.